# Assistance To Create a Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle10g

Hi guys I need to create a trigger in ORACLE 10g which ensures that a deathDate that is BEFORE the birthDate cannot be entered. I am really struggling on this please can you provide support thank you kind people.

My scheme is:

```
Actor (actorID, lastName, firstName, middleName, suffix, gender, birthDate, deathDate)
Movie (movieID, title, year, company, totalNoms, awardsWon, DVDPrice, discountPrice)
Quote (quoteID, quote)
Role (roleID ,roleName ,gender ,actorID* ,movieID*) 
RoleQuote (roleID*, quoteID*)
```

Thank you

If there is any more information that you require please ask

My relationship constraint are:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                C                                                
------------------------------ -                                                
QUOTE_FK                       R                                                
ROLE_FK                        R                                                
MOVIE_ROLE_FK                  R                                                
ACTOR_ROLE_FK                  R                                                
ACTORID                        P                                                
MOVIEID                        P                                                
QUOTEID                        P                                                
ROLEID                         P                                                
ROLEQUOTEID                    P       

Relationships:

ALTER TABLE Role ADD CONSTRAINT ACTOR_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (actorID) REFERENCES Actor (actorID);
ALTER TABLE Role ADD CONSTRAINT MOVIE_ROLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (movieID) REFERENCES Movie (movieID);
ALTER TABLE RoleQuote ADD CONSTRAINT Role_FK FOREIGN KEY (roleID) REFERENCES Role (roleID);
ALTER TABLE RoleQuote ADD CONSTRAINT Quote_FK FOREIGN KEY (quoteID) REFERENCES Quote (quoteID);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? [P.S...](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/index.php)

Comment: I will post:

CREATE TRIGGER death_date_not_valid BEFORE birthDate < deathDate;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER death_date_not_valid
  2  BEFORE INSERT ON deathDate
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  deathDate NUMBER;
  6  MAXMOD EXCEPTION;

Comment: I dont know if that's correct but that it is what i tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sort of constraint should be implemented as a `CHECK` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE actor
  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_birth_before_death CHECK( birthDate < deathDate );
```

If you really need the constraint to be enforced with a trigger (this will be slower and require more work)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_death_date
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON actor
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.birthDate > :new.deathDate )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Birth date cannot be later than death date.' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this and let you know god bless you

Comment: Do i need to add the alter table? or can i just run the trigger thanks

Comment: @user1137472 - You can either create the constraint or you can create the trigger.  It wouldn't make sense to do both.  My strong preference would be to enforce this rule using a constraint rather than using a trigger.

Comment: @user1337472, can I ask why you chose to implement a trigger, when it was strongly suggested (and I agree with the suggestion), that this should be implemented via a check constraint?

Comment: I am learning ORACLE it as a hobby and have never done oracle before therefore i wanted to try and test triggers this is only for self use as i am just trying to learn the different methods and teach my self triggers that is all